# Opening PSD file in Adobe Illustrator using ExtendScript

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to write a script to open PSD files in Adobe Illustrator and do some batch processing. The problem is I can't provide the needed open options.

From [docs](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015/Illustrator%20Scripting%20Reference%20-%20JavaScript.pdf):

> **Application**
>
> - **open**(File **file**, DocumentColorSpace **documentColorSpace**, Anything **options**)
>
>   Opens the specified document file.

...

> **OpenOptionsPhotoshop**
>
> Options for opening a Photoshop document, used with the **open** method.

So, I'm assuming I can use `OpenOptionsPhotoshop` with `open` method, but how?

I tried doing this:

```
var psdFile = new File('file.psd');

var options = new OpenOptionsPhotoshop();
options.preserveHiddenLayers = true;

app.open(psdFile, DocumentColorSpace.RGB, options);
```

But it says:

> OpenOptionsPhotoshop does not have a constructor.

Any ideas how to pass the options to the `open` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating an `OpenOptionsPhotoshop` object, you need to access it somehow. You can access it like this:

```
app.preferences.photoshopFileOptions.preserveHiddenLayers = true;
```

I found this by looking here:

https://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/Illustrator/Preferences/photoshopFileOptions
https://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/Illustrator/Application/preferences

Quick edit, the documentation for the `open` method is here too. The second and third params are optional.

https://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/Illustrator/Application/open

Comment: I used `app.preferences.photoshopFileOptions` to change the default options for opening PSD files, but thought there should be a way to skip the open dialog completely by passing `options` parameter.

Comment: @Hejazi to suppress alerts you would add this `app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;` then whatever preferences you set will be the default choices.

Comment: @styks It's been a long time since I wrote the script, so I can't test that now. I hope other people find your answer. Thank you!